# Call to a member function prepare() on a non-object and variable undefined

Tags: php

I am having  a very bad learn php day. Can someone tell me why this won't work?
I have errors call to member function() on non object ad undefined variable at line 23
here is the code:

```
<?php
// connect to the MySQL server
$conn = new mysqli('localhost', 'username', 'password', 'Org_db');

// check connection
 if (mysqli_connect_errno()) {
 exit('Connect failed: '. mysqli_connect_error());
 }
 //for insert user info into users table columns
 $id = '';
 $name = 'Bob Grundy';
  $pass = md5("secure");
  $email = 'bob@acgs.org';
  $reg_date = date("m/d/Y");
 //line 23
 if (!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `pass`, `email`, 
 `reg_date`)     VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?)")) {
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
 }
 /* Prepared statement, bind and execute */


if (!$stmt->bind_param("issss", $id, $name, $pass, $email, $reg_date)) {
echo "Binding parameters failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}

if (!$stmt->execute()) {
echo "Execute failed: (" . $stmt->errno . ") " . $stmt->error;
}
?>
```

Comment: You're nor declaring any value for $mysqli.

Comment: simply replace `$mysqli` with `$conn`

Answer (score 1):

You defined `$conn = new mysqli(..` but after you used `!$stmt = $mysqli->prepare("..`, here, `$mysqli` variable should be changed to `$conn` such as:

```
 if (!$stmt = $conn->prepare("INSERT INTO `users` (`id`, `name`, `pass`, `email`, 
 `reg_date`)     VALUES ( ?,?,?,?,?)")) {
echo "Prepare failed: (" . $mysqli->errno . ") " . $mysqli->error;
 }
```

Comment: thanks Jason, you guys sure relieve some headaches!!

Comment: @user2042111 You should accept this answer to close the question then.